# Utilizing Google Documents with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is there any way to: (After client has been logged in using their google account)

- Listing their Google Documents
- Editing their Google Documents
- Saving their Google Documents

in *Javascript*. Note that *everything must* be in Javascript.

Can it even be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been able to find anything with the [Google Data APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html), I do not believe what you want to do is possible. It looks like any interaction with Google Docs is server-side (Java, .NET, PHP, Python, Obj-C).

Maybe if you can describe why it has to be server-side, maybe you can get a satisfactory answer to what you are attempting to do (or why you are attempting to do it that way).

But, to answer your question - no, it's not possible at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how to use anything server side, and have not found any way to learn. I do know Java, though. How do I do server side java?

Answer (score 0):

yes that is possible:

google provides an [example](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/nodejs). I wrote code to edit delete etc in go.
I don't think why you need node.js. You should be able to use JAM and call the jsAPi directly from the browser.

there also is google apps script, which allows you to edit documents within google docs.